# How to apply Image Pre-processing Improve EasyOCR result on Blurred and Noisy Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

I'm attempting to extract text from an image using EasyOCR. However, the output isn't correct because the image is blurry. I intend to enhance the results by applying some image preprocessing. Here's the code I've used:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en','ko'])
# read the input
img = cv2.imread('/content/image (2).png')

# Apply EasyOCR to the image
response = reader.readtext(stretch)
text = " ".join([r[1] for r in response])
print(text)
```

[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVKTk.png)

Output from EasyOCR

```
현금이서 껍쳐본 점부 8무보기 코인전승화면 접처본 처부 성표모기
```

Can anybody help me improving the results

Comment: Try unsharp masking.  See skimage at https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/filters/plot_unsharp_mask.html

Comment: @fmw42 Can you modified the above code. so that the results could be better

Comment: Sorry, I have not used EasyOCR.

Comment: Does this help `cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored`?

Comment: @toyotaSupra No it does not help.

Comment: @fmw42 you can provide solution with other method